# PDF creation no longer works after switching from php version 7.0 to 7.1

Tags: php, mpdf

For security reasons I changed the php version on my server from 7.0 to 7.2. Right after that MPDF doesn't work anymore.

The following error appears:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Error detected. PDF file generation aborted: fopen(https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image-360x510.jpg): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/assets/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf/src/Image/ImageProcessor.php:223

The image exists. If I enter the link in the browser the picture appears.

To check if the new PHP version is the problem I put it back to 7.0. And see there, the PDF creation worked fine again.

I am using MPDF 7.1. According to the MPDF documentation the PHP version 7.1 or 7.2 should not be a problem.

Can anyone help me? I had the code for the problem and a detailed debug-log excerpt. but unfortunately i'm new here and somehow i'm not allowed to! Well then I hope someone can help me without code and debug.

Comment: Maybe you're missing some php extensions in your 7.2 install, like `mbstring` or `gd` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a configuration problem in your 7.2 php.ini.

You could try to enable `allow_url_fopen=On`, in your 7.2 `php.ini`